# Como formatar este array?

Tags: php, array

Tenho a seguinte array:

```
$dados = array(
    '0' => array(
        'id_assinante' => $id,  
        'nome' => 'Aluguel'  
    ),
    '1' => array(
        'id_assinante' => $id,  
        'nome' => 'Água'  
    ),
    '2' => array(
        'id_assinante' => $id,  
        'nome' => 'Contabilidade'  
    ),
    '3' => array(
        'id_assinante' => $id,  
        'nome' => 'Energia'  
    ),
    '4' => array(
        'id_assinante' => $id,  
        'nome' => 'Imposto'  
    ),
    '5' => array(
        'id_assinante' => $id,  
        'nome' => 'IPTU'  
    ),
    '6' => array(
        'id_assinante' => $id,  
        'nome' => 'Marketing'  
    ),
    '7' => array(
        'id_assinante' => $id,  
        'nome' => 'Telefone'  
    )               
);
```

Neste caso funciona perfeitamente, mas há alguma forma de fazer isso mais simplificadamente? Sendo que o `$id` será sempre igual, e cada valor do campo nome terá um nome diferente?

Comment: Esse array é montado fixo, igual está na pergunta?

Comment: Está ai o código... Sim é montado fixo, eu vou incluir os itens manualmente...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Queres qualquer coisa assim?

```
<?php

$array = array();

$id = "meu_id";

$nomes = ["Aluguel", "Água", "Contabilidade", "Energia",
          "Imposto", "IPTU",  "Marketing"   , "Telefone"]; 

$max = count( $nomes );

for( $count = 0; $count < $max; $count++ ) 
{
    $array[$count] = array(
        'id_assinante' => $id,  
        'nome'         => $nomes[$count] );  
}
```

Veja a funcionar: http://ideone.com/2wZVut

Answer (score 4):

Um jeito de fazer é assim:

O `$id` deveria ser global nesse caso. Se for pode ser usado assim:

```
function map_nomes($m){
    $id = 1;
    return ['nome' => $m, 'id_assinante' => $id];
}

$nomes = ['Aluguel', 
          'Água', 
          'Contabilidade', 
          'Energia', 
          'Imposto', 
          'IPTU', 
          'Marketing', 
          'Telefone'
          ];
$response   = array_map("map_nomes", $nomes);
```

### [Funcionando SandBox PHP](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6660508ef1736b23527035fb73d249678b26f74d)

Versão manual:

```
$dados = array(
    'id_assinante' => $id, 
    '0' => array(
        'nome' => 'Aluguel'  
    ),
    '1' => array(
        'nome' => 'Água'  
    ),
    '2' => array(
        'nome' => 'Contabilidade'  
    ),
    '3' => array(
        'nome' => 'Energia'  
    ),
    '4' => array(
        'nome' => 'Imposto'  
    ),
    '5' => array(
        'nome' => 'IPTU'  
    ),
    '6' => array(
        'nome' => 'Marketing'  
    ),
    '7' => array(
        'nome' => 'Telefone'  
    )               
);
```

Comment: Minha ideia seria fazer um pouco mais customizado, de forma que eu possa fazer com menos código repetitivo

Comment: Entendi. Então a maneira do Jorge é melhor. Achei que queria manualmente.

Comment: Coloquei uma outra forma de fazer também. Não sei se você desejaria assim.

Comment: não... o retorno precisa ser como eu mostrei, porque eu uso o insert_batch (do codeigniter), para incluir no banco de dados estes registros

Comment: Veja agora se é isso. Quer dizer, se quiser porquê você já tem a solução

Comment: Vejo sim, mas ainda não é, tem que retornar da maneira da array multi-dimensional senão não consigo inserir, mas eu tenho interesse em ter uma terceira opção, pra eu estudar mesmo, acho bacana isso. :) Agradeço seu empenho.

Comment: Entendi o que você precisa. Mas do jeito que fiz talvez não seja o caso então, usando o `array_map`.

Comment: Eu fiz uma alteração, se quiser ver como está.

Comment: Bacana, pode postar no PHP lá pra ver se dá certo? :)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50446/discussion-between-andre-baill-and-gumball).

Comment: Exatamente, é uma boa opção a sua também!

Answer (score 3):

A pergunta é vaga pois não se sabe de onde vem os dados e onde serão usados ou se há outras condições como um segundo ID de assinante, por exemplo.

Por hora, chutaria algo desse tipo:

```
$arr = array(
    'id_assinante' => $id,
    'servicos' => array('Aluguel', 'Água', 'Contabilidade', 'Energia', 'Imposto', 'IPTU',  'Marketing', 'Telefone');
);
```

Comment: É uma opção....

Answer (score 2):

Creio que o jeito mais fácil e mais organizado seria usando o [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php)

```
$id = 10;
$arr = array_map(function($index) use ($id) {
    $index['id_assinante'] = $id;
    return $index;
}, $dados);
```

Realizando o teste apenas com 3 elementos do array;

```
var_dump($arr);
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["nome"]=>
    string(7) "Aluguel"
    ["id"]=>
    int(10)
 }
 [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["nome"]=>
    string(5) "Água"
    ["id"]=>
    int(10)
 }
 [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["nome"]=>
    string(13) "Contabilidade"
    ["id"]=>
    int(10)
 }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["nome"]=>
    string(7) "Energia"
    ["id"]=>
    int(10)
 }
}
```

Desta maneira você não precisa fazer loops `for` ou `foreach` nem fazer lógicas bagunçadas com índices de array.

Comment: Mas cadê os nomes ? Coloca também para eu ver um jeito melhor de usar o `array_map`.

Comment: @Gumball os nomes você não precisa mexer, pois queremos apenas adicionar o indice "id" em cada array.

Comment: @RafaelAcioly pela sua conversa... foi você que deu -1? Qual o problema de ter loop ou índices? Sabe como é implementada a `array_map`?

Comment: Já agora o AP não quer só automatizar o id, também quer o resto.

Comment: @RafaelAcioly onde estão os nomes para inclusão? :) Obg por sua resposta.

Comment: @AndréBaill você quer montar um array bidimensional do 0? é isso? O que entendi na sua pergunta é que voce precisa adicionar o campo "id" em todos os arrays...

Comment: @JorgeB. a pergunta dele ainda esta um pouco confusa, o que ele quer na verdade é criar varios arrays dentro de um array com nomes dinamicos, descondidere minha resposta por favor